Minimal example using MOSEK API in python
I want to solve (simplified version)
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        & \underset{}{\text{find}} & & X\in\mathbb{S}^{n}_{+}, x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \nu \in \mathbb{R}, \lambda\geq 0\\ 
        & \text{subject to} & & E^{\top} X E + \lambda A + \nu B \succeq 0, \\ 
        & & & Fx + \lambda a + \nu b = 0, \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
    E &\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p},\\
    A &\in \mathbb{S}^{p}, \\
    B &\in \mathbb{S}^{p}, \\
    F &\in \mathbb{R}^{q \times m}, \\
    a &\in \mathbb{R}^{q}, \\
    b &\in \mathbb{R}^{q}
\end{align*}
are fixed.
I use Python with CVXPY and the MOSEK solver, which I find unreliable. Matlab with CVX and MOSEK is more reliable. I recently found that there is a MOSEK API for Python. However, the tutorial page does not directly cover this use case. I'm looking for a minimal example covering this case.
Edit: The following code passes without errors. However, contrary to Erling's mention below, dualization was not needed. Is this a correct implementation?
from mosek.fusion import *
import mosek.fusion.pythonic
import numpy as np

# Define the dimensions
n = 4
p = 3
m = 2
q = 2

# Generate random fixed data for the problem
np.random.seed()
E = np.random.randn(n, p)
A = np.random.randn(p, p)
A = (A + A.T) / 2  # Make A symmetric
B = np.random.randn(p, p)
B = (B + B.T) / 2  # Make B symmetric
F = np.random.randn(q, m)
a = np.random.randn(q)
b = np.random.randn(q)

# Create a new model
with Model("example") as M:
    # Define the variables
    X = M.variable("X", Domain.inPSDCone(n))
    x = M.variable("x", m, Domain.unbounded())
    nu = M.variable("nu", 1, Domain.unbounded())
    lam = M.variable("lambda", 1, Domain.greaterThan(0.0))

    # PSD constraint: E^T X E + lambda * A + nu * B >= 0
    M.constraint("psd_constraint", E.T @ X @ E + lam[0] * A + nu[0] * B, Domain.inPSDCone())

    # Linear equality constraint: Fx + lambda * a + nu * b = 0
    M.constraint("linear_constraint", F @ x + lam[0] * a + nu[0] * b, Domain.equalsTo(0.0))

    # Solve the problem
    M.solve()
    
    # Retrieve and print the solution
    X_sol = X.level()
    x_sol = x.level()
    nu_sol = nu.level()
    lam_sol = lam.level()
    
    print("Solution X:\n", np.array(X_sol).reshape((n, n)))
    print("Solution x:", x_sol)
    print("Solution nu:",nu_sol[0])
    print("Solution lambda:", lam_sol[0])


What did you find unreliable in CVXPY/MOSEK?

@MarkL.Stone The way CVXPY rewrites the feasibility problem to the MOSEK solver leads to worse numerical stability compared to CVX to MOSEK. As I sweep over some data parameters of the feasibility problem, for which I know that feasibility holds by known theorems, (CVX, MOSEK) can recover it to a greater extent than (CVXPY, MOSEK). Of course, the interesting case is the behavior in cases that are not covered by known theory.

The difference between CVX and CVXPY might come down to order of constraints or minor transformation differences; and if that is enough  to sway the results between feasibility and infeasibility, perhaps something is deficient in your model's input data, or the model itself. Have you looked at the beginning of the MOSEK output to see if there are warnings about large or small magnitude numbers? If so, you should rescale the input data (change units) so that all non-zero input data is within a small number of orders of magnitude of 1.

@MarkL.Stone, I believe the input variables are reasonable. You can have a look at a bad case here: https://ibb.co/1rbCm2K

@MarkL.Stone, another one: https://ibb.co/wpByfz1

In the bad cases, do you know whether there's a strictly positive definite feasible solution? if not, there could be a Slater condition violation, which might cause numerical difficulty for Mosek, and perhaps make it sensitive to the exact presentation of the problem. I will leave further diagnosis/assessment to Mosek employees, several of whom are on this board.

Your code looks good, it is analogous to what you would write in CVXPY and CVX. Regarding dualization a good place to start is https://docs.mosek.com/latest/faq/faq.html#why-is-my-sdp-lmi-slow-or-running-out-of-memory and the links therein. In your case I don't think it will matter since you don't really have an LMI but constraints binding two semidefinite variables ($X$ and the one implicit in $\succeq$.)

First observe problems that are not robust feasible or robust infeasible by  by definition are nasty. Since you are testing feasibility of your system, then it is likely to be the case sometimes, because that might be baked into what you are doing.
If you have a nasty (read illposed) problem, then tiny changes in the problem can change the outcome. As far as I recall CVX has an automatic dualizer which is likely to be invoked in this case and maybe it helps for some reason. For this and other reasons CVX and CVXPY are likely to feed different formulations to Mosek and hence produce different outcomes on nasty problems.
Btw if you want to use MOSEK directly, then using Fusion is likely to be easier. However, it still requires some work. SDP are just more complicated to do.
Since your problem includes an LMI, it is normally better to dualize the problem when you use Mosek directly since Mosek does not have an automatic dualizer yet.

When do you plan to introduce an automatic dualizer for SDPs?

Most likely not any time soon.

What about the edit/code in the original post above? Adding a constraint with Domain.inPSDCone() seems to work fine.

What I meant is, that it may be important for efficiency reasons to feed Mosek the dual problems in some cases. Based on the limited information you provided I thought it might be the case. However, @Michal Adamaszek writes above that dualizing should be needed in your case. You can trust his advice.
